# How do I mine gems and how do I build?

Tags: a-valley-without-wind

I have completed the first part of the game and I am now in the last cell of the map, where you can continue to the world map.
I have explored around 98% and scouted 100%. 
I also killed the Boss where you are told to turn around after finding new Spells.
Then I found the settlement.

My question is:

**How can I get those colored gems in the dungeons and how exactly do I build?** I am a bit confused about that atm :). Thanks for any answer.

Comment: Awesome to see some people asking about this game here.  :D

Comment: Did you really *have* to change the tag I created?

Comment: Well, I first I thought you'd cropped it to fit the tag limit... but it really *should* be the full name of the game, whenever possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use one of the touch spells (like Fire Touch spell you get first off) on the gem vein as if it was a monster you wanted to kill.

Paraphrasing from the [arcengames wiki](http://www.arcengames.com/mediawiki/index.php?title=AVWW_-_Everything_You_Wanted_To_Know_About_Missions,_But_Were_Afraid_To_Ask):
Building requires a guardian power scroll for the particular building and an NPC with a particular profession and enough skill in said profession

Comment: Note, as of the latest version, you no longer need the NPC with the profession/skill.  You just need a guardian power scroll for the building.  You may also need a world map location for some buildings.